# can't figure out why my IF statement is being skipped in SQL with C++

Tags: c++, sql

I can't seem to figure out why my IF statements are being skipped. Using SQL with C++. 
The program skips my first two IF statements and jumps down to the else branch. Not sure why this is doing this at all. this is my coding.

```
void add_technician() {
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    char sn[10];
    int s = 0;
    char answer;
    int umn;
    char tname[30];
    char tadd[30];
    char tpho[10];
    char tmod[15];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

cout << "Enter social security number:";
cin >> sn;  

EXEC SQL SELECT count(*) into :s from Employees where SSN= :sn;

          if (s == 1)
   { 
cout << "Employee already exists in the database."; 
   cout <<"Would you like to update the union-membership-number?";
   cin >> answer;
   if (answer == 'y'|| 'Y')
   {cout <<"Enter new union member number:";
   cin >> umn;
EXEC SQL 
    INSERT INTO Employee (ssn, union_member_no)
    VALUES (:sn, :umn);
 } 
   }
         else {
 cout << "Enter in union membership number of the new employee: ";
            cin >> umn;
            EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Employees (ssn, union_member_no) 
                   VALUES (:sn, :umn);
            EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
             cout << "Enter the address of the technician.";
             cin >> tadd;
 cout << "Enter the name technician name.";
             cin >> tname;

            EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Technicians (address, name , phone)
       VALUES (:tadd, :tname, :tpho);
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
            cout << "Enter airplane model number that you are an expert on." ;
            cin >> tmod;
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Experts (model_no, ssn)
    VALUES (:tmod);
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK; }                

}
```

Comment: does the SQL return count=0? Did you check your data/queries to be correct?

Comment: You say it 'skips' the if and just goes to the else, do you understand how if/else statements work? In your example it will hit the else blok whenever s is not equal to 1

Comment: it actually "skips" your first if statement because the second if is inside the first one

Comment: what i want to happen is when the user enters in an ssn, the program checks the database to see if that ssn is in the database. if the ssn is already in the database, the program says that ssn is already in the database and asks the user if they want to update the info.

Comment: am i not allowed to do a nested if statement?

Comment: Indentation hell aside, did you check the value of `s` right after the first `SELECT` with a debugger?

Comment: i am pre-compiling and compiling my program through putty

Comment: Not only that, but the second `if` statement is malformed.  `if (answer == 'y'|| 'Y')` will always evaluate to `true`.  You need to do it like this instead: `if ((answer == 'y') || (anwer == 'Y'))`

Comment: ok. for this part, if the user selects 'n' || 'N' how can i get it to display the menu options?when i try to code in an else, i keep getting an error

Answer (score 1):

The code is allowing a single SSN to have multiple UMNs assigned to it, but the first `if` statement is not taking that into account.  It is checking for a SSN that has only 1 UMN assigned to it.  If a given SSN has multiple UMNs assigned, the `SELECT` will return `count > 1` and flow will jump to your `else` block.

Also, your second `if` statement is malformed. `if (answer == 'y'|| 'Y')` will always evaluate to `true`. You need to specify the `answer` variable in each set of condition, like this: `if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'))`.

Try this:

```
void add_technician()
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
        char sn[10];
        int s = 0;
        char answer;
        int umn;
        char tname[30];
        char tadd[30];
        char tpho[10];
        char tmod[15];
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    cout << "Enter social security number:";
    cin >> sn;

    EXEC SQL SELECT count(*) into :s from Employees where SSN= :sn;

    if (s > 0)
    {
       cout << "Employee already exists in the database.";
       cout << "Would you like to add a new union membership number?";
       cin >> answer;
       if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'))
       {
           cout << "Enter new union member number:";
           cin >> umn;
           EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Employee (ssn, union_member_no)  VALUES (:sn, :umn);
       }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Enter union membership number of the new employee: ";
        cin >> umn;
        EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Employees (ssn, union_member_no) VALUES (:sn, :umn);
        EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;

        cout << "Enter the address of the technician.";
        cin >> tadd;
        cout << "Enter the name of the technician.";
        cin >> tname;
        EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Technicians (address, name , phone) VALUES (:tadd, :tname, :tpho);
        EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;

        cout << "Enter airplane model number that the technician is an expert on." ;
        cin >> tmod;
        EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Experts (model_no, ssn) VALUES (:tmod);
        EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried out your code, and when i add a new technician i can, but when i tried adding the same ssn, it doesn't give the message saying that the ssn is already in the database.

Comment: Then your `SELECT` is not working correctly.  Did you verify that what is stored in the DB is EXACTLY the same that the user typed in?  Also keep in mind that functions like `fgets()` and `getline()` DO NOT strip off the line break that ended the input, so make sure you strip that off yourself BEFORE inserting the strings into the DB.

Comment: I'm not sure why my select statement would not be working correctly. i'm using the same select statement as i have written in another portion of my code, but that selecct statement works fine. i'm not sure what could be wrong with the select statement. i see what you mean, but i'm not sure how my select statement could be incorrect.